# qt QWidget::closeEvent link issue

Tags: c++, qt

I have a pretty big app, which was running fine on windows with Qt5.10.0 and minGW32 compiler.
And then I added a new window based on QDialog. In that new class, I try to reimplement *QDialog::closeEvent*. In header file:

```
virtual void closeEvent(QEvent *pEvent) override;
```

Then, I get a warning

```
xxx::closeEvent hides overloaded virtual function
```

, because parameter is *QCloseEvent* type, and link errors.

So, I have tried to:

- reimplement closeEvent(Q**Close**Event *pEvent)
- delete closeEvent method
- stop to use that window and delete it from .pro

No matter my trials, the following links error remain, and avoid me to compile anymore:

```
undefined reference to `QWidget::closeEvent(QEvent*)'
```

on many moc_"guifile".o. All *moc_files.o* are generated though. Final error is:

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(Furthermore, Qt creator, claims that it can't find these moc files when I try to follow link from "issue" tab.)

The weird thing is that I never use *closeEvent* anymore, in any of source or generated files. *moc_files.cpp* do not contains any *closeEvent* string.

**But**
*moc_files.o*  **do** contain references to  *__ZN7QWidget10closeEventEP6QEvent*, for example, which is wrong (right signature is QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)), but how can I avoid it to be generated?

I have tried several time to clean/recompile/delete build folder.

Obviously, I don't hope to receive a solution here, but any tips for helping me to figure out where to search would be appreciated.

What could help? Reinstalling Qt/minGW seems no use, as it has worked from months?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you change anything using refactor tool?

Comment: Search for and delete any generated files under *source dir*. Sounds like case of that...

Comment: Also, check that any of these haven't been accidentally added to version control.

Comment: No generated files under source dir or under version control. It seems that all projects are broken, even the Qt examples. I just notice that qwidgets.h has changed yesterday evening ??? I don't know how this append, but that is for sure origin of problem. Does anybody knows where I can get a fresh <qt>/include/qwidgets.h? Anyway, thanks guys

Comment: Oh sorry, I put the mess in my include files. Now it is ok, thanks again, and sorry for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from a modification of Qt includes files

Comment: On Windows the Qt installation done without administrative privileges is not read-only... You could make it read-only, but that's a bit of a bummer indeed. Perhaps you could install and maintain your Qt installation under administrative privileges, essentially making Qt invariant for your use case.